# C http O_NONBLOCK mode issue?

Tags: c, http

I am learning the development of little http clients and specifically the whole complexity with NONBLOCKING tcp sockets with http/1.1 clients.

the little code below seems working on linux but not on my mac os x 10.6.8 .. after debugging it seems looping with the send function ? is there a difference with the non blocking mode between linux and mac os x/freebsd ?

this is what I receive ...

Connect to google.com(173.194.65.147) on port 80 ... ok 
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.52.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.2 Safari/534.52.7

sent failed: Socket is not connected

can someone help me understand what is going wrong in this code ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

void 
setSockNonBlock(int sock)
{
    int             flags;
    flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flags < 0) {
    perror("fcntl(F_GETFL) failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) < 0) {
    perror("fcntl(F_SETFL) failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int 
getIP(const char *uri, char *hostname, struct in_addr * ip)
{
    char           *tmp;
    tmp = (char *) malloc(strlen(uri) + 1);
    strncpy(tmp, uri, strlen(uri) + 1);
    char           *p, *q;
    p = strstr(tmp, "http://");
    if (p == NULL) {
    p = tmp;
    } else {
    p = tmp + 7;
    }
    q = strstr(p, "/");
    if (q != NULL) {
    *q = '\0';
    } else {
    q = tmp + strlen(uri);
    }
    strncpy(hostname, p, q - p + 1);
    free(tmp);

    struct hostent *host;
    if ((host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "gethostbyname failed, %s\n", hstrerror(h_errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int             i;
    for (i = 0; host->h_addr_list[i] != NULL; i++) {
    if (host->h_addrtype == AF_INET) {
        memcpy(ip, (struct in_addr *) (host->h_addr_list[i]), sizeof(struct in_addr));
        return 1;
    }
    }
    return 0;
}

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: %s uri\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char           *uri;
    uri = argv[1];

    char           *hostname;
    hostname = (char *) malloc(strlen(uri) + 1);
    struct in_addr  ip;
    if (!getIP(uri, hostname, &ip)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getIP for %s failed\n", uri);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char            ip_str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    if (!inet_ntop(AF_INET, &ip, ip_str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN)) {
    perror("inet_ntop failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int             sock;
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    setSockNonBlock(sock);

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr = ip;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) & serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == -1 && (errno != EINPROGRESS)) {
    perror("connect failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Connect to %s(%s) on port 80 ... ok \n", hostname, ip_str);

    char            request[1024] = "";
    char           *get;
    get = strstr(uri, hostname);
    if (get == NULL) {
    get = "/";
    } else {
    get += strlen(hostname);
    if (*get == '\0') {
        get = "/";
    }
    }

    sprintf(request, "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.52.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.2 Safari/534.52.7\r\n\r\n", get, hostname);
    printf("%s\n", request);
    free(hostname);

    char           *p = request;
    int             remaining = strlen(request);
    ssize_t         sent_size;
    while (remaining) {
    sent_size = send(sock, p, remaining, 0);

    if (sent_size == -1 && (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) {
        continue;
    }
    if (sent_size <= 0) {
        perror("sent failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    remaining -= sent_size;
    p += sent_size;
    }

    char           *resp = NULL;
    int             resp_size = 0;
    char            buf[1024];
    ssize_t         recv_size;

    char           *tmp;
    while (1) {
    recv_size = recv(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    if (recv_size == -1 && (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) {
        continue;
    }
    if (recv_size <= 0) {
        break;
    }
    tmp = (char *) realloc(resp, resp_size + recv_size + 1);
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: realloc failed, not enough memory to save response");
        if (resp) {
        free(resp);
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    resp = tmp;

    tmp = resp + resp_size;
    memcpy(tmp, buf, recv_size);
    resp_size += recv_size;
    resp[resp_size] = '\0';
    if (strstr(resp, "</html>")) {
        break;
    }
    }
    if (resp) {
    printf("%s\n", resp);
    free(resp);
    }
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When checking for error from `send`, don't use `sent_size <= 0`. Zero is a valid value to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is that you are doing a non-blocking connect() but immediately falling through some code which will take a few milliseconds to execute and then try to send on that socket that probably isn't connected yet.

You can do a simple test by sticking a sleep() for a few seconds in there after the connect to see if that is the actual cause.  But the larger problem is that, at least at the moment, you don't have any compelling reason to use non-blocking sockets since you aren't using doing anything with the time you would be otherwise blocked anyway.  For instance, your send loop doesn't do anything but check the return code and try to send again.  You might as well just block.  Maybe code taking advantage of non-blocking is where you are headed in the next phase?

In any case, look into [select()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) or [poll()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) (and friends like `pselect`, `ppoll`, ...).  It will be helpful in multiplexing.

Comment: I added a sleep(2) just after the connect but now the application seems to wait in a infinite loop ...

Comment: @Vincent Blondel - I ran your pgm but blocking or non-blocking you just hang (or loop) in the recv which means you aren't getting sent any data.  You may want to check what you are sending.

Comment: @VincentBlondel You haven't coded it to detect when it has received all the data. So it keeps waiting for more even though it's received all of it. What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to avoid using existing HTTP related libraries like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) for the HTTP client part and [D.Moreno's Onion](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion) or [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/s/libmicrohttpd/) on the HTTP server side?

Writing your own HTTP protocol stack is quite time consuming!!!